# How to change all sentence case words into uppercase in word 2013 using wildcards

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, wildcards

How can I change all sentence case words into uppercase in word 2013 using wildcards or using the Find and Replace feature?

**Examples:**

- Convert Hello to HELLO
- Convery Balloon to BALLOON

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be done using the find/replace feature you can simply select the entire sentence and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to cycle between lowercase, uppercase and sentence case.

Comment: Found in Google. Using this <[A-Z][a-z]@>

Comment: @JabirJabi if that is your solution then you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found in Google. Using this <[A-Z][a-z]@>

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so and provide some instructions on how to apply it.